# Powershell through CMD or VBS getting FileVersion

Tags: powershell, batch-file, vbscript, cmd

Okeys, I'm at a loss of understanding something. It might be in here somewhere already, but I'm haveing some trouble explaining it to myself, so I'm also haveing trouble searching for it.

The thing isn't really complicated, just illogical to me. I'm trying to set up a script in Powershell that mainly goes into a folder and gets the versions of all the `*.exe files`. And that works quite well like this :

```
dir 'C:\Program Files (x86)\SPN'| Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include '*.exe' |%{$_.VersionInfo} | select FileName, FileVersion | Format-Table -Autosize | Out-file c:\test.txt
```

It's pretty simple as all it does is go into the folder, recursivly searching for the exe files, taking out the VersionInfo and then selecting the FileNames and Versions before putting it into a file as to make a report of the versions installed. And it works too!

The problem is a bit more complicated. We use a `htm\vbs application` to run scripts. Mainly it means that all our scripts be it `vbs, batch, or powershell` is run through this platform. Sometimes we also run a powershell through a batch file started by a vbs script.

When I start powershell and run the script above a file is outputed with the information I'm after, when I start a cmd and run the powershell script I get a list of the applications without the versions. Same goes for vbs.

So I thought I'd go more deep. I started a cmd, and typed in `start powershell` to get a new window that way, but alas, I still only get the `filenames and no versions!` The only way I get the versions is to run the script through Powershell it self. ( meaning I have to manually open Powershell, as right clicking and selecting `Run with Powershell` gives names, and no versions )

Any suggestions and ideas would be welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Alright, digging even deeper I found that it actually was working. The problem with the cmd was actually that there was no room on the screen. Adding "mode con: cols=145" solved that one. I haven't tryed to solve it in vbs, but I suppose it's probably something similiar. Closing the case. - Guessing I can't close it ;) I found my answer in any case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some columns might not be displayed if you specify the widest columns first, so it is safest to specify the smallest data elements first. In the following example, we specify the extremely wide path element first, and even with wrapping, we still lose the final column.

Specify fileversion first fixes the problem.

```
dir 'C:\.....| Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include '*.exe' | %{$_.VersionInfo} | select FileName, FileVersion | Format-Table -Wrap -Autosize -Property fileversion, filename | Out-File "C:\....\testing.txt"
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347677.aspx